# Cómo convertir campo varchar a tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una tabla tengo un campo varchar que almacena un tiempo "01:42:41", he intentado varias opciones y no he podido lograr sumar este campo para poder saber el total de tiempo gastado.

Ejemplo:
campo 1 -> 01:30:00
campo 2 -> 01:30:00

Necesitaría poder sumar estos 2 campos para que el total me de 3:00 Horas.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir que DBMS usas y qué código has intentado? Y como me gusta meterme con la optimización, ¿por qué declaraste el campo como `varchar` y no como  `time` o como `datetime`?  Espero que no estés usando **varias columnas** para representar un dato que al fin y al cabo es el mismo, incurriendo en una mala práctica.

Comment: Estoy usando SQL, el sistema lo crearón así en visual fox pro y ahora las tablas de fox se están migrando a SQL y para generar un informe con ese tipo de campo ha estado muy complicado poder hacer la suma total de tiempo

Comment: Pero ¿la base de datos está en qué en Fox Pro?

Comment: no, esos datos se migrarón así a SQL y ahora en SQL nos encontramos con el problema de realizar una sumatoria como tal de esos tiempos

Comment: Pero ¿cuando hablas de SQL a qué te refieres: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL ...? Hay muchos DBMS, ¿cuál estás usando?

Comment: SQL SERVER, disculpas!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ejemplo en [Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017), tenemos el tipo de dato [time](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Puedes convertir cadenas con el formato adecuado

```
CONVERT(TIME, '1:30:00')
```

Pero no puedes, sumar dos tipos time.
Pero si puedes convertirlos a DATETIME y sumarlos

```
CAST(@Tiempo1 AS DATETIME) + CAST(@Tiempo2 AS DATETIME)
```

Y luego, volverlos al tipo de dato que necesitas

```
CONVERT(TIME, CAST(@Tiempo1 AS DATETIME) + CAST(@Tiempo2 AS DATETIME))
```

Un ejemplo

```
DECLARE @TiempoEnCadena1 VARCHAR(100) = '01:30:00',
    @TiempoEnCadena2 VARCHAR(100) = '01:30:00',
    @Tiempo1 TIME,
    @Tiempo2 TIME,
    @TiempoTotal TIME

SET @Tiempo1 =CONVERT(TIME, @TiempoEnCadena1)
SET @Tiempo2 =CONVERT(TIME, @TiempoEnCadena2)

--SET @TiempoTotal = @Tiempo1 + @Tiempo2

SELECT 
    Tiempo1 = @Tiempo1,
    Tiempo1 = @Tiempo2,
    --TiempoTotal1 = @Tiempo1 + @Tiempo1,  --Error > El tipo de datos time del     operando no es válido para el operador add.
    TiempoTotal = CONVERT(TIME, CAST(@Tiempo1 AS DATETIME) + CAST(@Tiempo2 AS DATETIME))
```

Enlaces que te pueden servir

- [Time | Define una hora de un día. La hora no distingue la zona horaria y está basada en un reloj de 24 horas.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 1):

Jassan

Esto sirve para oracle, si tu base no es oracle te puede servir la lógica de solución de todas formas.

```
/* Tiempo 1:30:25  + 2:25:34 = 03:55:59
Puedes sumar 32 horas con 40 horas y te dira 72 horas con sus minutos y segundos respectivos */
SELECT
/* Paso segundos a formato de tiempo hh-mi-ss*/
TO_CHAR(TRUNC((T1+T2)/3600),'FM9900') || ':' || 
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((T1+T2),3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' || 
TO_CHAR(MOD((T1+T2),60),'FM00') AS TIEMPO_SUMADO
FROM
/*Transformo fechas a segundos*/
(SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR('1:30:25','[^:]+',1,1)*60*60 + REGEXP_SUBSTR('1:30:25','[^:]+',1,2)*60 + REGEXP_SUBSTR('1:30:25','[^:]+',1,3) AS T1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('2:25:34','[^:]+',1,1)*60*60 + REGEXP_SUBSTR('2:25:34','[^:]+',1,2)*60 + REGEXP_SUBSTR('2:25:34','[^:]+',1,3) AS T2
FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: La idea sería apoyar pero en la herramienta mencionada y no en una equivalente

Comment: Claro, pero me parece que Jassan comento después cual DB usaba, por eso yo le escribí esta respuesta.